# Making a falling object in "Physical properties"-rigid body soft

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

I have a rigid body simulation of a falling object.
Now I would like to make that falling object **soft** to see how is it deformed when it hits
the bottom plane. Where do I set that softness ?

Answer (score 0):

Keyword: Rigid. Because of the simulation methods, Rigid Body simulations do not allow physically calculated deformations. If you do want those, I suggest you use a soft body or cloth simulation with optimized settings.